# Simulate the web browser experience with graphics

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm searching for something, which can help me to represent HTTP request to user, with measure its events. I need:

1. Ability to measure full page request with all redirects, resolves for page and its sub-resources (like [OctaGate SiteTimer](http://www.octagate.com/service/SiteTimer/)):
   [image]
2. Ability to load pages as real browser - simulate the work of real browser.

I know about the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class, but it provide very small functionality to measure the subresources download, and is available only for Windows applications.
Do you have any ideas about tools which can help me, or just some directions for developing such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the context of your requirements and constraints but perhaps using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and writing a custom extension would be a good starting point? Depends on the technical level of your user as to whether this would cut it. Essentially Fiddler sets itself up as a proxy server so it can intercept and forward all requests. So if you had to roll your own, that would be one way to do it, but there would be a lot of work involved.